# "Чтобы ты (?) и пришел вовремя?"

Tags: пунктуация

Какой знак препинания нужно поставить в предложении?

**Чтобы ты (?) и пришел вовремя? Это что-то новое.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Чтобы ты — и пришел вовремя?**

> Союз «да», обозначающий невозможность сомнения, уверенность в
> обратном, не требует знаков препинания.
>
> *Наш Федя да обманщик? Ни за что не поверю!*

В нашем случае союз "и" выступает в той же роли (но я бы использовал "да"). Думаю, тире можно поставить для усиления экспрессии, но тогда лучше завершить предложение соответствующим знаком — "?!".

Answer (score 3):

Обычно используется союза ДА и ставится восклицательный знак: **Чтобы ты да  пришел вовремя!**  (Союз ДА можно просто убрать из предложения).

Примеры:

Квартирмейстер, вскинув руки, воскликнул: ― **Чтобы я да кому-нибудь сказал!** Могила! [А. С. Новиков-Прибой. Цусима (1932-1935)]

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F7%F2%EE%E1%FB+%FF+%E4%E0+

Можно при наличии паузы поставить **тире,** в этом случае возможны оба союза (И и ДА).

Мне никто не верил, да и сейчас не верят, говорят: «Да брось! **Чтобы ты ― да была одна!**

**Чтобы я ― и сдрейфил?!** [Сергей Таранов. Черт за спиной (2001)]